# Script to kill multiple process with same session using scripts

Tags: bash, script, powershell

How can I kill a process running with in multiple sessions using a bash or powershell script?

Comment: your question and your body state different things, please elaborate your question

Answer (score 3):

On Windows-machines with powershell installed, you can just do this:

`get-process PROCESS_NAME | stop-process`

Answer (score 2):

Bash alternative

> `pgrep killus | while read p; do kill -9 $p; done`

kills all processes named killus

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to automate this, or just to have a tool available where you can manually kill multiple instances of a process by name, regardless of what user session any instance is running in? I'm assuming the latter, and the following should accomplish that.

On Windows, you can't beat Sysinternals' "pskill" utility. [Get the SysInternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062), unpack, and at a command prompt simply use `pskill theprocessname` to deep-six all instances of the corresponding executable.

The following bash script would provide similar functionality on Linux; I'll leave it to the user to figure out how to loop it until no more instances exist:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 -eq ""]; then
echo "Usage : ./pkill.sh <process name>"
else
get_proc=`ps -e -o pid,command | grep $1`
echo $get_proc > get_it
get_pid=`gawk -F" " '{ print $1 }' get_it`
kill -9 $get_pid
fi
```

(Script lifted directly from http://www.linuxweblog.com/kill-process-name, but pasting it here for posterity because I hate finding dead links in answers on StackExchange sites.)

Hope this helps!